# How to convert array to dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, data-science

My output from previous code.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DOCTOR") 
row = cursor.fetchall()
row
```

[image: output]

how to convert array into data frame. expected output is shown in the below picture.
[image: Expected output picture]

how to convert array to dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

df = DataFrame(data=np.array(row), 
               index=np.arange(len(row)), 
               columns=['Doctor_id','Doctor_Name','Doctor_Spl'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a plain cursor from a SQL client

Pandas has its own [`read_sql` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) that wraps a SQL client library and returns a Dataframe

You can also do most SQL queries directly from Dataframe objects, if you were to start with `read_sql_table` - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html#compare-with-sql

Answer (score 0):

converting the fetched row to numpy array and using that to convert to data frame

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DOCTOR") 
row = cursor.fetchall()
numpy_array_row = np.array(row)
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(numpy_array_row, columns=['Doctor_id', 'Doctor_Name', 'Doctor_Spl'])

# print your data_frame and voila :)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `pandas.DataFrame()` method.
In your case it would look like this:

```py
DataFrame(row, columns=('Doctor_id', 'Doctor_Name', 'Doctor_Spl'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```py
rows = [
    ("D001", "TIM1", "orthopedic"),
    ("D002", "Ram", "General medicine"),
    ("D003", "Sarala", "gynaecology"),
    ("D004", "TIM", "Ayurvedic"),
    ("D005", "viny", "Hemeopathy"),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Doctor_id", "Doctor_Name", "Doctor_Spl"])
df.index += 1  # <-- if you need index starting from `1`
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Doctor_id Doctor_Name        Doctor_Spl
1      D001        TIM1        orthopedic
2      D002         Ram  General medicine
3      D003      Sarala       gynaecology
4      D004         TIM         Ayurvedic
5      D005        viny        Hemeopathy
```